# Powershell: Find the currently logged on user and copy a unique file from a shared drive

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables, copy-item

Title says most of it. I have generated unique files for users who will be running their scripts remotely. The script is supposed to find the name of the currently logged on user and copy that unique file to C:\Users\Public. Currently however I am running into an issue where the system seems to default to my username. I have tried multiple methods sourced from here and stack overflow and cannot seem to get a good result, as everyone ends up with my unique file. I have tried the following:

```
$env:username

$env:userprofile

$currentuser=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
```

The script looks as such:

```
$currentuser=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name

if ($currentuser = "Domain/username1") {
copy-item -Path "shared network location\username1file" -Destination "C:\Users\Public"
}
elseif ($currentuser = "Domain\username2") {
copy-item -Path "shared network location\username2file" -Destination "C:\Users\Public"
}
elseif ($currentuser = "domain\username3") {
copy-item -Path "shared network location\username3file" -Destination "C:\Users\Public"
}
```

Can anyone provide me any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: You have provided insufficient information for us to assist you. Please explain the exact process you're using to deploy/run the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the currently logged on user and not the user currently running the script, you can use WMI `Win32_ComputerSystem`.

Also, I would recommend using `switch` instead of multiple `elseif`:

```
$currentuser = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName

$file = switch ($currentuser) {
    'Domain\username1' { "shared network location\username1file"; break }
    'Domain\username2' { "shared network location\username2file"; break }
    'Domain\username3' { "shared network location\username3file"; break }
    default { $null }
}

if ($file) {
    Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination "C:\Users\Public"
}
else {
    Write-Host "No file to copy defined for user '$currentuser'"
}
```